# Resize font proportional to screen size?

Tags: fonts, responsive-webdesign

How can I have my fonts scale based on screen size?

(So, rather than just having a few media queries to adjust to maybe 3 or 4 screen sizes, have the font be proportional to the screen size so we make maximum use of the screen.

I need to support all browsers back to ie6.
It's OK if the support is not "pretty" on browsers with < 1% market share but it should at least be usable.

I've considered:

- vm  (% of viewport size) : not well supported.
- [FitText.js](http://fittextjs.com/)
- Using Ems  (this seems to at least adapt somewhat. (If I view it on my phone and change from landscape to portrait the font gets a bit smaller. I"m guessing maybe the phone/browser is resizing the base font in that case.
- using a *lot* of Media queries (10 or 20) and perhaps using EM for all sizes so we only have to set the base (body) font size in the media query.

Comment: Why would there be 20 different media queries if your using 3-4 screen sizes... You use mobile, tablet, desktop, and larger. That's 4... and you use `rem` to get the root size which in turn will change all the rest.

Comment: There are 10 different commonly used (>5% each) sizes on desktops alone. Not to mention all the different phone makers, tablet makers and sizes (there about 10 sizes on this page alone: http://www.ciop.com/common-resolutions-for-mobile-phones-and-tablets/

Comment: You shouldn't need to have more than 4 different styles for devices, a font size should work on all mobiles. The pages a `640px` device should look no different than a device than `600px` this is because you use `em` or `rem` which will scale based on the device that is being viewed, along with media queries, this method is used by most professional run websites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my CSS I use percentages for font size changes and make sure that font-size is set to `inherit` on all element types

```
h1 {
    font-size: 200%
}
h2 {
    font-size: 150%
}
table {
    font-size: inherit;
}
```

Then JavaScript just needs to adjust the *base* font size of the document or body.

```
$("body").css("font-size",Math.max($(window).width()/50,8)+"px")
```

That particular statement relies on jQuery, but it should be doable without jQuery as well.

[Here is a page](http://savvyroo.com/frame-1389518839750-active-quarterbacks-with-the-most-4th-quarter-comebacks) where I use the technique to get a chart to take up the entire screen with appropriate sized fonts.